# How to pass SPAM filters?

Tags: email, postfix, spam, dovecot

I just configured Postfix and Dovecot, I can send and receive emails. At the moment I have a problem with Hotmail, all my email are saved on the SPAM folder. My MX has few days, maybe they will control my MX and then set it to their "whitelist".

However, supposing to have DNS configured correctly and a clean IP address, what are the steps to follow to improve the possibilities to pass Hotmail's (and other) SPAM filter?

I have started to use the SPF record on my DNS (TXT) and set the reverse IP to my mail.example.com MX.

...

then ?

Comment: And many others here

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that your server is not on an IP block that has been identified by your ISP as dynamic.
2. Contact Hotmail for assistance/consideration, if #1 is in affect.